# Finding all polygons inside of a polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, well-known-text, st

How to find all the polygons inside of a polygon? I tried ST_Intersects and ST_Contains but they are booleans variables. I have a list of polygons in WKT format, so I am trying to pull all the polygons given a region in their WKT format.

Does anyone have an idea how to approach this?

```
select geom from polygon where 
ST_Intersects(ST_GeographyFromText
('POLYGON((210000 2400000, 300000 2300000, 330000 3708400, 210000 2400000))'), 
polygon.geom);
```

Comment: Please share the SQL you tried.

Comment: @WKT I added in the SQL. Please take a look.

Comment: What is the end result you are looking for? Have you looked at ST_Intersection?

Comment: The result of your ST_geografyFromText is "POLYGON((120 -60,120 -40,-120 40,120 -60))" .  Is it correct ? This cast is probably not what you want...

Comment: @kflaw the end result should be a list of polygons in WKT formats that are inside of the given polygon.

Comment: SELECT ST_AsText(geom) ...

Comment: now I tried : 
ST_Intersection(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((210000 2400000,       300000 2300000, 330000 3708400, 210000 2400000))'),geom) from polygon and I am getting all GeometryCollection Empty. I checked the data and make sure those number in the polygon would intersect with a least one polygon. Is there something I did wrong?

Comment: I think ST_intersection is not what you want. What is the CRS of these coordinates ?

Comment: I posted an answer below, which should work for you if both of your datasets are in the same coordinate system

Comment: @WKT  EPSG:4326 is the CRS

Comment: @moffittime It can't. Look at bounds here: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/

Comment: @WKT thank you! I just realize my CRS isn't set it correctly

Comment: ST_Intersects or ST_Contains will give different results. ST_Intersects will also return polygons that are only partially contained, or even just touch. ST_Contains is more restrictive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing ST_AsText, as @WKT mentions above. This should work for you:

```
select ST_AsText(geom) from polygon
where ST_Intersects(ST_GeographyFromText
('POLYGON((210000 2400000, 300000 2300000, 330000 3708400, 210000 2400000))'), 
polygon.geom);
```

Comment: why the downvote? I tested this with my own data (using different coordinates) and it worked.