# ST_Transform error

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, well-known-text, st

I am getting an error from ST_Tranform while using ST_Intersection:
No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

```
select ST_Intersection(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((
200000 2900000,250000 3500000,300000 2960000,200000 2967400,200000 
2900000))',96703),4326), ST_Transform((geom, 2249), 4326))
from polygon_folder;
```

Comment: You forgot a function around `(geom, 2249)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do this:

```
  select ST_Intersection(
  ST_Transform(
      ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((
    200000 2900000,250000 3500000,300000 2960000,200000 2967400,200000 
    2900000))'),96703),4326), 

ST_Transform(geom, 4326))
from polygon_folder;
```

But, I am quite sure (from [Finding all polygons inside of a polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197409)) that  ST_Intersection is not really what you need....

Comment: So what is a good way to find all the polygons that intersect with a given polygon? @WKT

Comment: About `select * from polygon_folder pf where ST_Intersects(pf.geometry, ST_GeomFromText('....');`