# Check whether a point is inside a polygon or not in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the points those are within the shapefile. I have tried the Spatial functions and it's showing an error:

> ## 3033 - Binary geometry function st_contains given two geometries of different srids: 4326 and 0, which should have been identical.

My query is

```
SELECT 
lightning.lightning_id, lightning.latitude, lightning.longitude,
lightning.flash_type, 
DATE_FORMAT(lightning.lightning_time, '%D %b %Y %T %p') as lightning_time 
FROM lightning, districts_s 
WHERE 
ST_CONTAINS(districts_s.SHAPE, Point(lightning.longitude, lightning.latitude)) 
AND lightning.height > 50
```

To rectify the error I got a solution from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197489/st-transform-error?noredirect=1&lq=1) and this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32709/query-failed-error-operation-on-two-geometries-with-different-srid) but no result, as this also showing an error:

> ST_Transform does not exist

## update 1

ERROR ON ST_SetSRID
[image]

Comment: The `Point` function is not setting an SRID. You can use `ST_SetSRID(Point(lon,lat),4326)`

Comment: Tried the same but got an error called ST_SetSRID does not exist. Check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this, on both layer:

```
UPDATE districts_s SET SHAPE = ST_SetSRID(SHAPE, 4326)
```

But I guess the problem is with lightning, you should save lightning.latitude and lightning.latitude to a geometry (point) column.

Comment: Yes I tried to update the same but it shows me an error called "mydb.ST_SetSRID does not exist"

Comment: Maybe try ST_SRID, or UPDATE Table SET SpatialColumn = ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(SpatialColumn), 4326);
But I still think that the problem comes from the lightning, what should be in a spatial column as well.

Comment: You mean to say my lat,long should be in a point geometry column?

Comment: Right solution, wrong operand. The table data is fine, but the geometry calculated on the fly doesn't have an SRID.

Comment: I checked my SRID of that geometry column using ST_SRID and it's SRID is 4326