# Finding polygons inside polygons from a shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, qgis-plugins, spatial-query

I have a parcels shapefile that contains polygons. Condos are also drawn, but inside the master lot. I want to be able to grab all the condos inside the master lot. I saw this question/answer:
 [Finding all polygons inside of a polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197409/finding-all-polygons-inside-of-a-polygon), but that is for POSTGIS and I'm working with shapefiles. I'm writing a plugin for owners lists, so I need this type of search to be included in order to get a complete owners list. The spatial query doesn't allow a search on the same layer which is a problem.

The basic question is: **How do I select polygons inside polygons within the same shapefile?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a **custom script** containing the following function which essentially:

1. Let's you select the master lot (in case you have more than one in your shapefile).
2. Uses a spatial index to add all features (which intersect the master lot) to a list.
3. Deselects the master lot.
4. Selects all features which lie inside the master lot.

You can create a script from:

```
Processing Toolbox > Scripts > Tools > Create new script
```

Then use something like the following:

```
##Select_within_polygons=name
##Polygon_layer=vector polygon

from qgis.core import QgsSpatialIndex

layer = processing.getObject(Polygon_layer)

# Create spatial index
index = QgsSpatialIndex()
# Get master lot
m_lot = layer.selectedFeatures()
for f in m_lot:
    master_lot = f
# Iterate through all features and add to index
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    index.insertFeature(feat)
    # List to find features which intersect master lot 
    id_list = index.intersects(master_lot.geometry().boundingBox())
# Remove master lot from list
id_list.remove(master_lot.id())
# Deselect master lot
layer.deselect(master_lot.id())
# Select features from id_list
layer.setSelectedFeatures(id_list)
```

Make sure the script is saved in your `/.qgis2/processing/scripts/` directory. Before you run the script, select the master lot from your layer.

---

Example:

1. A simple polygon containing smaller polygons inside.

   [image: Before running script]

---

2. Now we select the bigger polygon:

   [image: Selecting master lot]

---

3. Then run the script to see the selected polygons inside:

   [image: Result]